# In Apache POI Word, is it possible to hide a row in a table?

Tags: java, apache, ms-word, apache-poi, xwpf

Manually we can to it by selecting the whole row and setting the font to Hidden (described here: http://www.wordbanter.com/showthread.php?t=101661).

My question is, how to do this using Apache POI Word (XWPF)?

Comment: Not clear what is meant with "set the font to Hidden". I would simply set the row height as small as possible to hide the row.

Comment: If the "and set the font to Hidden" means something along the lines of [this article](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/ms-office-tips/word-hidden-text/), then you should mention this in your question. This can be answered then, although it hides the table row only in print view and in screen view which not shows hidden text elements. So the row is not truely hidden.